# Why does my OpenVPN not route the network behind?

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN Network with some clients.
One of the Clients haves a full network with Printers.
The Server is running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the Printserver on Debian 8.11.

The Server.conf looks like that:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.170.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "route 10.133.10.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

The Printservers Client.conf looks like that:

```
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 168.119.40.249 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 5
pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway
```

Still, not even the server can Ping any of the Printers.

I assumed, that the routing may not have been added, but it is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
10.133.10.0     10.170.0.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.133.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.170.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

Also, i added following to the printservers iptables:
`-A INPUT -s 10.170.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT`

still, the Printserver can Ping the Printer:

```
ping 10.133.10.1
PING 10.133.10.1 (10.133.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.133.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.149 ms
64 bytes from 10.133.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.139 ms
64 bytes from 10.133.10.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.128 ms
```

But the OpenVPN-Server (or any client) can't:

```
ping 10.133.10.1
PING 10.133.10.1 (10.133.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.133.10.1 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12281ms
```

The Logs of the Client-OpenVPN:

```
openvpn /etc/openvpn/server.conf
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=251723 Current Parameter Settings:
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=251924   config = '/etc/openvpn/server.conf'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=251980   mode = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252029   persist_config = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252079   persist_mode = 1
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252125   show_ciphers = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252179   show_digests = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252225   show_engines = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252270   genkey = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252318   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252363   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252410   connect_retry_max = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252456 Connection profiles [0]:
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252502   proto = tcp-client
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252547   local = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252592   local_port = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252637   remote = '168.119.40.249'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252686   remote_port = '1194'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252732   remote_float = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252776   bind_defined = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252822   bind_local = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252867   bind_ipv6_only = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252914   connect_retry_seconds = 5
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=252959   connect_timeout = 120
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253006   socks_proxy_server = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253052   socks_proxy_port = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253100   tun_mtu = 1500
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253164   tun_mtu_defined = ENABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253211   link_mtu = 1500
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253264   link_mtu_defined = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253311   tun_mtu_extra = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253365   tun_mtu_extra_defined = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253419   mtu_discover_type = -1
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253465   fragment = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253519   mssfix = 1450
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253573   explicit_exit_notification = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253626 Connection profiles END
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253680   remote_random = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253732   ipchange = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253784   dev = 'tun'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253835   dev_type = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253889   dev_node = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253941   lladdr = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=253995   topology = 1
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254046   ifconfig_local = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254100   ifconfig_remote_netmask = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254157   ifconfig_noexec = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254210   ifconfig_nowarn = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254264   ifconfig_ipv6_local = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254318   ifconfig_ipv6_netbits = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254370   ifconfig_ipv6_remote = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254423   shaper = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254470   mtu_test = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254514   mlock = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254559   keepalive_ping = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254605   keepalive_timeout = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254650   inactivity_timeout = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254728   ping_send_timeout = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254774   ping_rec_timeout = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254819   ping_rec_timeout_action = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254911   ping_timer_remote = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=254963   remap_sigusr1 = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255007   persist_tun = ENABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255051   persist_local_ip = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255106   persist_remote_ip = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255153   persist_key = ENABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255201   passtos = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255248   resolve_retry_seconds = 1000000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255295   resolve_in_advance = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255341   username = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255396   groupname = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255450   chroot_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255498   cd_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255554   writepid = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255603   up_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255648   down_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255699   down_pre = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255744   up_restart = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255790   up_delay = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255835   daemon = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255882   inetd = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=255939   log = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256001   suppress_timestamps = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256053   machine_readable_output = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256111   nice = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256164   verbosity = 5
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256210   mute = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256268   gremlin = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256318   status_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256364   status_file_version = 1
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256417   status_file_update_freq = 60
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256469   occ = ENABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256515   rcvbuf = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256561   sndbuf = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256606   mark = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256656   sockflags = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256700   fast_io = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256756   comp.alg = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256807   comp.flags = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256851   route_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256905   route_default_gateway = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=256958   route_default_metric = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257009   route_noexec = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257056   route_delay = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257109   route_delay_window = 30
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257161   route_delay_defined = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257212   route_nopull = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257263   route_gateway_via_dhcp = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257313   allow_pull_fqdn = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257358   Pull filters:
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257411     ignore "redirect-gateway"
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257462   management_addr = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257507   management_port = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257560   management_user_pass = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257612   management_log_history_cache = 250
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257660   management_echo_buffer_size = 100
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257801   management_write_peer_info_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257849   management_client_user = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257896   management_client_group = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257945   management_flags = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=257990   shared_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258036   key_direction = not set
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258097   ciphername = 'AES-256-CBC'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258143   ncp_enabled = ENABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258189   ncp_ciphers = 'AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258235   authname = 'SHA512'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258282   prng_hash = 'SHA1'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258329   prng_nonce_secret_len = 16
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258381   keysize = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258432   engine = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258478   replay = ENABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258532   mute_replay_warnings = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258584   replay_window = 64
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258630   replay_time = 15
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258674   packet_id_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258725   use_iv = ENABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258776   test_crypto = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258828   tls_server = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258909   tls_client = ENABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=258956   key_method = 2
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259002   ca_file = '[[INLINE]]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259058   ca_path = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259110   dh_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259161   cert_file = '[[INLINE]]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259208   extra_certs_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259257   priv_key_file = '[[INLINE]]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259302   pkcs12_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259347   cipher_list = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259392   cipher_list_tls13 = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259443   tls_cert_profile = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259488   tls_verify = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259544   tls_export_cert = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259595   verify_x509_type = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259640   verify_x509_name = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259692   crl_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259743   ns_cert_type = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259789   remote_cert_ku[i] = 65535
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259840   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259886   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259938   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=259989   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260040   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260090   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260135   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260184   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260232   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260285   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260336   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260381   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260433   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260485   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260535   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260580   remote_cert_eku = 'TLS Web Server Authentication'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260634   ssl_flags = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260684   tls_timeout = 2
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260729   renegotiate_bytes = -1
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260783   renegotiate_packets = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260835   renegotiate_seconds = 3600
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260882   handshake_window = 60
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260935   transition_window = 3600
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=260986   single_session = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261031   push_peer_info = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261084   tls_exit = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261134   tls_auth_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261185   tls_crypt_file = '[[INLINE]]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261237   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261284   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261337   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261388   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261433   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261483   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261530   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261578   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261626   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261684   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261736   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261787   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261832   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261885   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261935   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=261980   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262036   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262087   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262133   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262187   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262238   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262284   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262337   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262388   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262439   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262490   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262536   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262585   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262632   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262685   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262737   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262789   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262840   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262903   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=262952   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263006   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263056   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263101   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263153   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263203   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263249   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263301   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263352   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263397   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263449   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263500   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263546   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263593   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263641   pkcs11_pin_cache_period = -1
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263689   pkcs11_id = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263744   pkcs11_id_management = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263816   server_network = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263867   server_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263936   server_network_ipv6 = ::
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=263989   server_netbits_ipv6 = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264048   server_bridge_ip = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264103   server_bridge_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264156   server_bridge_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264206   server_bridge_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264256   ifconfig_pool_defined = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264305   ifconfig_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264359   ifconfig_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264409   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264459   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264507   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264559   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_defined = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264621   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_base = ::
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264674   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_netbits = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264728   n_bcast_buf = 256
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264779   tcp_queue_limit = 64
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264830   real_hash_size = 256
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264876   virtual_hash_size = 256
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264928   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=264975   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265028   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265079   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265126   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265176   tmp_dir = '/tmp'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265221   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265275   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265325   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265375   push_ifconfig_ipv6_defined = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265425   push_ifconfig_ipv6_local = ::/0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265479   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265524   enable_c2c = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265576   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265627   cf_max = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265679   cf_per = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265725   max_clients = 1024
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265776   max_routes_per_client = 256
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265827   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265874   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265925   auth_token_generate = DISABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=265971   auth_token_lifetime = 0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=266023   port_share_host = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=266068   port_share_port = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=266118   client = ENABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=266164   pull = ENABLED
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=266209   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=266274 OpenVPN 2.4.9 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Apr 16 2020
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=266338 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.08
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=268773 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=268919 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=268984 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=269048 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=269273 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1623 D:1154 EF:96 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=269401 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1623 D:1450 EF:123 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=269514 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1603,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA512,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=269568 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1603,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_SERVER,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA512,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=269655 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]168.119.40.249:1194
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=269754 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Sun Jun 12 20:44:33 2022 us=269811 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]168.119.40.249:1194 [nonblock]
Sun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=270392 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]168.119.40.249:1194
Sun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=270551 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Sun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=270595 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]168.119.40.249:1194
WRSun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=295598 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]168.119.40.249:1194, sid=524c914c 8714a143
WWRWRSun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=367225 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ChangeMe
Sun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=368405 VERIFY KU OK
Sun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=368498 Validating certificate extended key usage
Sun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=368565 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Sun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=368626 VERIFY EKU OK
Sun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=368684 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server
RWWWRRWRWSun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=497066 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Sun Jun 12 20:44:34 2022 us=497258 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]168.119.40.249:1194
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=670987 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
WRRSun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=759338 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 10.133.10.0 255.255.255.0,sndbuf 512000,rcvbuf 512000,route-gateway 10.170.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.170.0.19 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=759756 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=759832 OPTIONS IMPORT: --sndbuf/--rcvbuf options modified
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=759905 Socket Buffers: R=[372480->425984] S=[87040->425984]
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=759976 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=760030 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=760083 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=760136 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=760189 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=760243 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1626
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=760308 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=760379 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=760481 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1554 D:1450 EF:54 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=760952 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=761040 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=761769 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.178.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth2 HWADDR=00:0d:b9:3d:e8:82
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=762707 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=762822 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=762965 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=763065 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=767441 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.170.0.19/24 broadcast 10.170.0.255
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=771677 /sbin/ip route add 10.133.10.0/24 via 10.170.0.1
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=775371 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Sun Jun 12 20:44:35 2022 us=775477 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

What am i doing wrong?
I need to get it working for my final exam.

Edit1:
i appended following to the `server.conf`

```
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
route 10.133.10.0 255.255.255.0
```

i created the ccd-directory and added a file named `server_hq` as the printservers CN is (which stands in the logs).

This now contains:

```
ifconfig-push 10.170.0.19 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.133.10.0 255.255.255.0
```

Logs of the connection of server_hq (printserver)

```
Sun Jun 12 21:25:36 2022 MULTI: Learn: 10.133.10.40 -> server_hq/<IP>:19295
Sun Jun 12 21:28:18 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19295 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Sun Jun 12 21:28:18 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19295 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Sun Jun 12 21:29:04 2022 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]<IP>:19294
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]<IP>:19294, sid=9264ab12 043d9161
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ChangeMe
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server_hq
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 peer info: IV_VER=2.4.9
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 peer info: IV_PLAT=linux
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 peer info: IV_PROTO=2
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 peer info: IV_NCP=2
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 peer info: IV_LZ4=1
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 peer info: IV_LZ4v2=1
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 peer info: IV_LZO=1
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 peer info: IV_COMP_STUB=1
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 peer info: IV_COMP_STUBv2=1
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 peer info: IV_TCPNL=1
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 <IP>:19294 [server_hq] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]<IP>:19294
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19294 OPTIONS IMPORT: reading client specific options from: /etc/openvpn/ccd/server_hq
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19294 MULTI: Learn: 10.170.0.19 -> server_hq/<IP>:19294
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19294 MULTI: primary virtual IP for server_hq/<IP>:19294: 10.170.0.19
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19294 MULTI: internal route 10.133.10.0/24 -> server_hq/<IP>:19294
Sun Jun 12 21:29:05 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19294 MULTI: Learn: 10.133.10.0/24 -> server_hq/<IP>:19294
Sun Jun 12 21:29:06 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19294 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Sun Jun 12 21:29:06 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19294 SENT CONTROL [server_hq]: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,sndbuf 512000,rcvbuf 512000,route-gateway >Sun Jun 12 21:29:06 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19294 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Sun Jun 12 21:29:06 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19294 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Sun Jun 12 21:29:06 2022 server_hq/<IP>:19294 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Sun Jun 12 21:29:25 2022 MULTI: Learn: 10.133.10.40 -> server_hq/<IP>:19294
```

Then i restarted both OpenVPN's and tried to ping one of the Printers ... without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your clients on the VPN network be able to reach your printers, the following are needed:

- A `route` advertisement for the clients (that you already have)
- A proper route on the OpenVPN server, pointing to the printers
- An `iroute` entry for the printserver
- For the above, a client config entry for your printserver's network
- Finally, proper routing on your print server

Also, technically it is not required, but you might want to assign a fixed IP address for your print server on the VPN.

So, first of all, you need a client config directory on the OpenVPN server. This can be anywhere, and can be called anything. Create a directory, then add this line to your `server.conf`:

```
client-config-dir /the/client-config-directory
```

Into that directory, put a file named the same as the print server's CN (that is, the CN field of the certificate used by the print server). That file should contain this:

```
ifconfig-push 10.170.0.254 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.133.10.0 255.255.255.0
```

This will ensure the print server will always get a fixed IP address (`10.170.0.254`), and that the OpenVPN server will be aware of the subnet behind the print server. You will also need a proper `route` entry in the kernel's routing table, so add this line to your `server.conf` as well:

```
route 10.133.10.0 255.255.255.0
```

With this setup, your VPN server will know where to route the packets going to your servers. One last thing to consider is the network setting of your print server and your printers. The setup above creates a routed network, so your printers will see connections coming from inside the VPN (i.e. from addresses `10.170.0.x`). The printers must know that these should be routed back to the VPN, and they must have the means to do so. If your print server is the default router for them, then all you need to do is to allow traffic between the VPN subnet and the local subnet on the firewall of the print server. If there is another computer acting as the default gateway, then you need to ensure the printers will route packets back to the print server. In this case, either add custom routes to the printers, or set up a NAT on the print server.

Comment: I made the changes, you explained pretty well, but still, i can't ping on any of the printers. I wrote those changes as Edit1

Comment: okay ... i cleared my whole iptables, just to test ... it worked ... means one of my rules is blocking it :D so, it is actually working.
somehow this line got added: `-A POSTROUTING -s 10.170.0.0/24 ! -d 10.170.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source <IP>`